# A metrizable Lindelöf space has a countable basis

Tags: general-topology

$X$ is called *metrizable Lindelöf space* if $X$ is a metrizable space and every open covering of $X$ contains a countable subcovering. Would you help me prove that $X$ has a countable basis? Thanks

Comment: This question from Munkres book exercise 30

Comment: Note that every compact space is Lindelöf, so this result implies the one in your [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234018/compact-metrizable-space-has-a-countable-basis-munkres-topology/234020#234020).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

HINT: Essentially the same hint that I gave for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234018/compact-metrizable-space-has-a-countable-basis-munkres-topology/234020#234020) works here. For each positive integer $n$ let $\mathscr{U}_n=\left\{B\left(x,\frac1n\right):x\in X\right\}$; this is an open cover of $X$, so it has a countable subcover $\mathscr{B}_n$. Consider $\mathscr{B}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\mathscr{B}_n$.

Answer (score 5):

In the metrizable space $X$, the following conditions are equivalent, cf. General Topology by Engelking Page 255:

> $X$ is separable
>
> $X$ is second countable
>
> $X$ is Lindelöf
>
> $X$ has countable extent
>
> $X$ is star countable
>
> $X$ is  CCC

Comment: You should have said 256 not 255

Answer (score 4):

I didn't want to start a new thread but wanted to see if my proof is kosher.

Note: This proof requires the assumption that every metrizable space with a countable dense subset has a countable basis.

Let $X$ be a metrizable Lindelhof space.

(Then as above)

For each positive integer $n$ let $\mathscr{U}_n=\left\{B\left(x,\frac1n\right):x\in X\right\}$; this is an open cover of $X$, so it has a countable subcover $\mathscr{B}_n$. Consider $\mathscr{B}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\mathscr{B}_n$.

I want to show $\mathscr{B}$ is dense in $X$.

Let $x\in X$, then let $B(x,\epsilon)$ be a basis element containing $x$. Then there exists an $n$ s.t. $x\in B(x', n)$ for some $x'$. But this implies that $x' \in B(x,\epsilon)$. So $x$ $\in \overline{\mathscr{B}}$, therefore $\overline{\mathscr{B}} = X$. Therefore $X$ has a countable basis since it contains a countable dense subset.